# How to use GETUTCDATE() of the database from c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an insert statement like

```
cmd.CommandText = @"insert into mytable (Filename,LastName,FirstName,CreateUTC) values (@Filename,@LastName,@FirstName,@CreateUTC)";
            ----
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreateUTC", SqlDbType.DateTime);
-
-
cmd.Parameters["@CreateUTC"].Value = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

But is it possible to use the sql's inbuilt  `GETUTCDATE()` to be triggered when inserting instead of me adding it from modifying this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a SQL function, simply call that function instead of using a parameter:

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES (..., @FirstName, GETUTCDATE())
```